# Change the distance between nodes in Graphviz

Tags: graphics, graphviz

I'm using graphiz to generate some graphics, I'm using `twopi` to draw a circle of nodes. One node in the midle as a root. this is whet I get :

[image: My Graph]

I need to change the distance between the root `A` and the other nodes  individually. So I used the `minlen` attribute, but that doesn't work for me.

this is the code:

```
digraph G {
 ranksep=3;

"1" [ label="A",shape="box",style="filled", fillcolor="#FCD975" ];
"2" [ label="B",shape="box",style="filled", fillcolor="#FCD975" ];
"3" [ label="C",shape="box",style="filled", fillcolor="#FCD975" ];
"4" [ label="D",shape="box",style="filled", fillcolor="#FCD975" ];
"5" [ label="D",shape="box",style="filled", fillcolor="#FCD975" ];
"6" [ label="D",shape="box",style="filled", fillcolor="#FCD975" ];


"1"-> "2" [ label=" ",color="blue" ,minlen="1"];
"1"-> "3" [ label=" ",color="blue", minlen="4" ];
"1"-> "4" [ label=" ",color="blue" ];
"1"-> "5" [ label=" ",color="blue", minlen="3" ];
"1"-> "6" [ label=" ",color="blue" ];
}
```

Any idea how to draw a star graphic, and configure the distance between the nodes individually?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation minlen is only supported by dot. But you could use len if neato or fdp will work for you instead of twopi